# Forms api validate float

Tags: forms

when using the Drupal FAPI and needing a float number field you have to use type textfield.  What's the best way to validate that this data is a float during hook_form_validate9)?  Is there a built in function. or do you have to do is_float()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because form input is always a string, is better to use [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

See [is_float()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) note.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal does not have an `is_float()` wrapper function. So yes, if you want to check to see if a string is a float, use PHP's native `is_float()`.

Answer (score 0):

The FAPI provides the ability to define a validation callback on any element.  Many of the validation callbacks you would like to use already exist.

See:  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/element_validate_number/7.x

You would use it like this:

```
$form['my_numeric_field'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('My Numeric Field'),
  '#element_validate' => array('element_validate_number'), 
);
```